# Save Data , Dataset + Windows + DataGrid View

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a customer table

[image]

I am using dataset

```
INSERT INTO [customer] ([full name], [email], [phone], [address], [city], [state], [country], [comment]) 
       VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8)
```

I am not able to save data into database. What's wrong?

I change to Uppercase for start letters now 'Full Name' instead of 'full name' (I was PHP developer). Here is my form view

[image]

Here is my dataset view

[image]

Comment: `C` tag is irrelevant. And show your full code please..

Comment: not sure about c# @ semantics but don't you need to quote some of those values. otherwise log your sql and see what your database says

Comment: i use the query builder from Dataset

Comment: what does "I am not able to save data into database" means? Does it give you some error?

Comment: I want to insert data , using the 'project_name.exe'. Updated my question

Comment: need some code what you have tried...

Comment: i think there is a problem while inserting data for arguments please show us the code to get a quick help

Comment: I need to code behind to add data? Sorry I am a newbie. I thought  Data Gridview is automated .

Comment: you want to add data from gridview into database right?

Comment: yes , want to add from datagridview